# How to rename all the elements in array in json using jolt?

Tags: javascript, json, jolt

I have JSON data coming thru external application A where which need to be sent to application B . And before the data goes to application B, all the attributes in the json need to be renamed.

for example , incoming json data structure is -

```
{
  "Array1": [
    {
      "field1": "foo1",
      "field2": [
        "bar1",
        "bar2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "field1": "foo2",
      "field2": [
        "bar3",
        "bar4"
      ],

      ...

        {
      "field1": "fooN",
      "field2": [
        "barX",
        "barY"
      ] 

    }
  ]
}
```

Where number of elements in `Array1` are variable per record.

The expected output is -

```
{
  "ElementList": [
    {
      "Attr1": "foo1",
      "Attr2": [
        "bar1",
        "bar2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Attr1": "foo2",
      "Attr2": [
        "bar3",
        "bar4"
      ],

      ...

        {
      "Attr1": "fooN",
      "Attr2": [
        "barX",
        "barY"
      ]  

    }
  ]
}
```

Basically

- Array1 renamed to ElementList
- each Field1 in Array1 renamed to Attr1
- each Field2 Array1 renamed to Attr2

For simple rename, I can use `shift` operator but I am not able to specify correct jolt transformation for arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585360/rename-fields-in-nested-arrays-using-jolt-transformation

Answer (score 0):

Chect if this suits you:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Array1": "ElementList"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ElementList": {
        "*": {
          "field1": "ElementList[&1].Attr1",
          "field2": "ElementList[&1].Attr2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yup , that’s what I came up with based on related question the other user pointed out.