# Apache NiFi: JoltJSONTransform to update a list of JSONs?, Real problem: Excess of processors

Tags: json, apache-nifi

First of all, thanks for your help.

I'm working with Apache NiFi, converting a list of JSONS in one FlowFile to several FlowFiles each one with one JSON.

Then, I'm using a JoltJSONTransform to update a key, missing in the json, present on attributes (filename)

My problem is that took me a lot of time, because I'm working with big files. My next task is try to modify the key in each element present on the list of JSONs, before I split it in several flowfiles.

My data is something like:

```
[
{ "number": "1",
  "pokemon":"Bulbasaur",
  "type":"plant"
},
{ "number": "4",
  "pokemon":"Charmander",
  "type":"fire"
},
{ "number": "7",
  "pokemon":"Squirtle",
  "type":"water"
}
]
```

And I'm trying to add the key:value "filename":"pokemon.csv". Same key to each dict inside the list...

And this is my best try, I think...
[image: best try]

Does anyone know how I can do it?

First of all, I have no idea about use scripts in Nifi :(

Edited: My problem is the excess of processors in NiFi. I have to use a python script in NiFi to replace 6 processors with only one, and now it works good enough. Thanks for your time

Comment: Instead of using JoltTransform , You could use `SplitJson`to split large file in individual records and then your either `ReplaceText` with  replacement value as `$1,"${filename}}"  or use UpdateRecord . If you have to go with jolt, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585360/rename-fields-in-nested-arrays-using-jolt-transformation

Answer (score 0):

SplitJson will load the entire file into memory, create smaller (split) flowfiles and commit those to the `Splits` relationship. The metadata for all those smaller flowfiles is held in heap memory space, which may result bad performance and even OOM (Out Of Memory) errors. I believe there are two common practices to remedy this.

First, when splitting large files, you can use a series of SplitText processors to chunk the original data e.g. every 10.000 lines. The second SplitText processors then splits those chunks into into the final size. This will reduce the heap memory footprint.

Second, you may use record-aware processors like SplitRecord with their associated Writers/Readers. These where developed to avoid the multiple split issue.

---

The solution really depends on the size of you Json. Here is a start:

- Use [SplitRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitRecord/index.html) to split Json list into chunks (of e.g. 1000)
- Use [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) to transform the chunks
- Use [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) to merge the chunks back together (optional depending on your use case)

Overall flow:

[image]

**GenerateFlowFile**:

[image]

SplitRecord:

[image]

Create a JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter, leave the default settings. Configure the split size. I set it to two because my list has three objects and I want to see two chunks.

**JoltTransformJSON**:

[image]

Jolt spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "filename": "filename.csv"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**MergeRecord**:

[image]

Create a JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter, leave the default settings. I set `Minimum Number of Records` to three, because I want all the records to be merged.

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: just a note: the SplitRecord produces  `record.count` attribute, and it could be used in merge processor.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't convince me, because my problem is the excess of processors. I finally relented and  I took the code from this git: https://gist.github.com/mattyb149/fa02e1060b0a6dc9f2a3c119863e862b in which you can find how to build a NiFi processor from a python script. It replaces 6 NiFi processors by 1 NiFi-Python scripted processor

Comment: @Krakenudo Why is your goal to have fewer processors? The idea of NiFi is to divide and conquer a work flow. You can group processors into process groups to organize your canvas. As I said their are multiple ways of solving this and I described a solution that would actually solve your problem without custom scribts.

Comment: My goal is to run this task fast enough. I take the workflow and I modify it with Attributes and vice versa, which takes a lot of time to do it. The flows ¿glue? before some processors, especially before UpdateAttribute's and ReplaceText's processors. If I take 6 processors and use one python's script processor instead,  I reduce the runtime from one day to 15 minutes. The amount of data is 500Mb in 250 files more or less....